# Facebook login implementation in ASP.net MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, facebook, razor

[image]I am learning ASP.net MVC 5. I am trying to implement the application using FACEBOOK login-in but I am getting following error message.

Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the App's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.

Any idea Why I am getting this error message AND/or missing any part. I am using the following URL to access my application.

https://localhost:44313/

Thanks
MAP
[image]

Comment: You can follow this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on

Comment: Thanks for sharing link. I tried steps mentioned in link but getting same error.

Comment: Have you definitely given Facebook the permission to handle requests from this domain? [Please see the article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on#creating-the-app-in-facebook-and-connecting-the-app-to-the-project)

Comment: I tried with fresh application just for facebook Login but stil same error.

Comment: After clicking, Application tried to open facebook link but then it is giving an error. It is not asking for Permission(Not reaching to that place).

Comment: I tried Google also but getting error,

Comment: 401. That’s an error.

Error: invalid_client

The OAuth client was not found.

Request Details
response_type=code
client_id=y-E4T5hjFZrFo0ps0Xb8NmaS
redirect_uri=https://localhost:44351/signin-google
scope=openid profile email
state=JrnECg4sZ4zlwfp86XaRWcBFzb16-7cDKsdRPJ_XXXcojo50uhP5edGP9qSf--KPNbDMFpAn0U0hDXaghDBA7jIPIhWze1uqNBfOa9fw9rDZ2QR53MctQ5ABSghvnxhE2TJgMDlpyCshCLbfENttSqEDg2X3Xno_Owmu_XOLQUAnEjAY-Estz6oMK7-x9xCqCfrOYMijkD4gTTojnh4H2kBszuQst9rJ1zYaYsV8kgA
That’s all we know.